# The Laws of Physics and 4-Vectors/4-Tensors

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, covariance

I have been trying to understand why the physics, in general, is written in 4-vectors and 4-tensors. Like, how do they relate to the main postulates of special relativity?

I am assuming that is it based on Enstines'Two Postulates.

Comment: Do you understand why we like to write Newtonian mechanics using 3-vectors and 3-tensors?

Comment: "Enstines" ?? possible typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be aware of time dilation and length contraction, two consequences of the two postulates. These are oart of something more general, called the Lorentz transformation. Lorentz transformations describe how space and time change under a change in velocity. In special relativity, vectors and tensors transform like tensors under Lorentz transformations. The transformations and the objects that behave like tensors under them can be derived from the postulates of special relativity. This is what makes them so useful in relativity.